# Regex matching if maximum two occurrences of dot and dash

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that will match any string containing at most 2 dashes and 2 dots.
There does not HAVE to be a dash nor a dot, but if there is 3+ dashes *or* 3 dots or even both 3+ dashes and 3+ dots, then the regex must not match the string.

Intended for use in PHP.
I know of easy alternatives using PHP functions, but it is to be used in a large system that just allows filtering using regular expressions.

Example string that will be MATCHED:
hello-world.com

Example string that will NOT be matched:
www.hello-world.easy.com *or* hello-world-i-win.com

Comment: Can you explain why you need such a requirement? Are you trying to validate urls?

Comment: I don't see how an URL with more than two dots would be invalid :-) However, it is for filtering OUT url's that are too complex and seem autogenerated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this matching your expectations?

```
(?!^.*?([.-]).*\1.*\1.*$)^.*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u4g1)

`(?!^.*?([.-]).*\1.*\1.*$)` is a negative lookahead. It matches the first `.-` put it in the capture group 1, and then checks if there are two more of them using hte backreference `\1`. As soon as it found three, the expression will not match anymore.

`^.*$` matches everything from start to the end, if the negative lookahead has not matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `(?!^.*?([-.])(?:.*\1){2}.*$)^.*$`

Answer (score 1):

This tested regex will do the trick:

```php
$re = '/# Match string with 2 or fewer dots or dashes
    ^                            # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){0,2}$)   # Assert 2 or fewer dots.
    (?=[^\-]*(?:-[^\-]*){0,2}$)  # Assert 2 or fewer dashes.
    .*                           # Ok to match string.
    $                            # Anchor to end of string.
    /sx';
```