# Regex to limit specific characters within a group

Tags: regex, match, regex-group

I struggle to change my current pattern:

**`^[\\\/0-9]{5,10}$`**

Which checks if input comprises of 5-10 numbers, slashes or backslashes.
I would like to limit total slash and backslash count to two at most.

e.g. *`12345/\\9`* should not be valid after the change:

I tried dissecting them into a separate group like so **`^([\\\/]{0,2}[0-9]){5,10}$`** but am getting wrong matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex matching if maximum two occurrences of dot and dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547187/regex-matching-if-maximum-two-occurrences-of-dot-and-dash)

Comment: Hmm, I just realized your problem is slightly different, because the question I linked counts dots and dashes separately. You'll have to make a small change to the regex from that answer: `^(?!.*?[\\\/].*[\\\/].*[\\\/]).*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a pattern using a lookahead anchored at the start of the string that tests one of the two "global conditions": the string length or number of slashes.

To limit the number of slashes you can design your pattern like this:

```
^[0-9]*(?:[/\\][0-9]*){0,2}$
```

Then you only have to add the condition for the string length in the lookahead assertion `(?=...)`:

```
^(?=.{5,10}$)[0-9]*(?:[/\\][0-9]*){0,2}$
```

*(note that you have to escape the forward slash only if the pattern is delimited by slashes. Otherwise the slash isn't a special character.)*

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should do the job:

```
^(?=[^\\\/]*(?:[\\\/][^\\\/]*){0,2}$)[\d\\\/]{5,10}$
```

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/cR9yH9/3) to try a working demo.